# Strip specific characters in a substring

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following list:

```
dates = ["05/05/19", "05/12/18"]
```

And I need to strip the day, which would be the second numeric value.

How would I be able to do so? Im allowed to use Numpy

My attempt but it returns the same thing:

```
import numpy as np

dates = ["05/05/19", "05/17/18"]
dates1 = np.array(dates)
dates2 = np.char.strip(dates1, "/")
print(dates2)
```

Comment: Could you provide intended output examples? Based on your question I believe you want output `["05/19", "05/20"]`?

Comment: Can you make it clear what you expect as output?

Comment: `np.char.strip` applys the `string.strip` method.  `strip` removes leading and trailing characters, not internal ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on "/" and pick the second element.

```
days=[  x.split("/")[1] for x in dates]
days
['05', '12']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string `split` with slicing and `join`:

```
dates = ['/'.join(x.split('/')[::2]) for x in dates]
```

Or a regex:

```
import re
dates = [re.sub(r'/\d+/', '/', x) for x in dates]
# ['05/19', '05/18']
```